# How to use a variable from Ansible to a Python script to create a list of users in the Spacewalk API

Tags: python, ansible

Using Ansible, Python and Spacewalk API,
My aim is to synchronise users from a FreeIPA group to create local users in Spacewalk, which will then be able to use their IPA password to login.

I have tested the creation of users and enabling PAM authentication manually, and this works fine, but now i want to automate this process.

I'm running Python 2.7.3 & Spacewalk 2.10

Here is my Ansible script **(details anonymised)**:

**spacewalk_sync_users.yml**

```
---
- name: Sync users from IPA group to Spacewalk
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: List all members of a given group
      ipa_group:
        name: <group_name>
        state: present
        ipa_host: <ipa_hostname>
        ipa_user: <admin_user>
        ipa_pass: <hidden>
      register: group_info
      delegate_to: <ipa_hostname>

    - name: Set IPA userlist fact
      set_fact:
        ipa_users_list: "{{ group_info.group.member_user | list }}"

    - name: compare IPA and Spacewalk users
      script: /path/to/compare_users.py "{{ ipa_users_list }}"
      register: comparison_result
      delegate_to: <spacewalk_hostname>

    - name: Set users to create variable
      set_fact:
        users_to_create: "{{ comparison_result.stdout_lines | join (',') }}"

    - name: create users in spacewalk
      script: /path/to/create_users_spacewalk.py "{{ users_to_create }}"
      delegate_to: <spacewalk_hostname>
```

Here are the python scripts which connect to Spacewalk's API:

**compare_users.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmlrpclib
import sys

# Spacewalk API URL and credentials
spacewalk_url = "http://<spacewalk>/rpc/api"
spacewalk_username = "admin_user"
spacewalk_password = "hidden"

def get_spacewalk_users():
    client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(spacewalk_url, verbose=False)
    session_key = client.auth.login(spacewalk_username, spacewalk_password)
    spacewalk_users = [user['login'] for user in client.user.listUsers(session_key)]
    client.auth.logout(session_key)
    return spacewalk_users

def compare_users(ipa_users, spacewalk_users):
    users_not_in_spacewalk = [user for user in ipa_users if user not in spacewalk_users]
    return users_not_in_spacewalk

def main():
    ipa_users = sys.argv[1].split(', ')
    spacewalk_users = get_spacewalk_users()
    users_not_in_spacewalk = compare_users(ipa_users, spacewalk_users)

    for user in users_not_in_spacewalk:
        print(user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**create_users_spacewalk.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmlrpclib
import sys

# Spacewalk API URL and credentials
spacewalk_url = "http://<spacewalk>/rpc/api"
spacewalk_username = "admin_user"
spacewalk_password = "hidden"

def set_spacewalk_vars():
    global client, session_key
    client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(spacewalk_url, verbose=True)
    session_key = client.auth.login(spacewalk_username, spacewalk_password)

def generate_user_data(user):
    # Generate user data based on the username
    first_name = username.split('.')[0].capitalize()
    last_name = username.split('.')[1].capitalize()
    email = "{}@some-email.com".format(user)
    return {
        'desiredLogin': username,
        'desiredPassword': 'password',
        'firstName': first_name,
        'lastName': last_name,
        'email': email,
        'usePamAuth': '1'
    }

def create_user_in_spacewalk(user_data):
    try:
        result = client.user.create(session_key, user_data)
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error creating user:", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

def main():
    set_spacewalk_vars()  # Call the function to set variables
    users_to_create = sys.argv[1].split(',')

    for username in users_to_create:
        user_data = generate_user_data(username)
        create_user_in_spacewalk(user_data)

    # Logout after creating all users
    client.auth.logout(session_key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The Output from running the Ansible playbook is as follows**

```
PLAY [Sync users from IPA group to Spacewalk] **********************************************************************************

TASK [List all members of a given group] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost -> <IPA_HOST>] => {"changed": false, "group": {"cn": ["<GROUP_NAME>"], "description": ["Active team members"], "dn": "cn=<GROUP_NAME>,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=ipa,dc=domain,dc=name", "gidnumber": ["<GID_NUMBER>"], "ipauniqueid": ["<UNIQUE_ID>"], "member_group": ["some_group"], "member_user": ["first.last1", "first.last2", ...], "memberofindirect_role": ["some_role"], "objectclass": ["top", "groupofnames", "nestedgroup", "ipausergroup", "ipaobject", "posixgroup"]}}

TASK [Set IPA userlist fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"ipa_users_list": ["first.last1", "first.last2", ...]}, "changed": false}

TASK [compare IPA and Spacewalk users] *****************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> <SPACEWALK_HOST>] => {"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stderr": "Shared connection to <SPACEWALK_HOST> closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to <SPACEWALK_HOST> closed."], "stdout": "['first.last1'\r\n'first.last2'\r\n...]\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["['first.last1'", "'first.last2'", "...]"]}

TASK [Set users to create variable] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"users_to_create": ["first.last1", "first.last2", ...]}, "changed": false}

TASK [create users in spacewalk] ***********************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoneType: None
fatal: [localhost -> <SPACEWALK_HOST>]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to <SPACEWALK_HOST> closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to <SPACEWALK_HOST> closed."], "stdout": "send: \"POST /rpc/api HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: <SPACEWALK_HOST>\\r\\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\\r\\nUser-Agent: xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)\\r\\nContent-Type: text/xml\\r\\nContent-Length: 237\\r\\n\\r\\n<?xml version='1.0'?>\\n<methodCall>\\n<methodName>auth.login</methodName>\\n<params>\\n<param>\\n<value><string>SPACEWALK_ADMIN</string></value>\\n</param>\\n<param>\\n<value><string>SOME_STRING</string></value>\\n</param>\\n</params>\\n</methodCall>\\n\"\r\nreply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n'\r\nheader: Date: SOME_DATE_TIME\r\r\nheader: Server: Apache\r\r\nheader: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\r\nheader: Content-Length: 207\r\r\nbody: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><methodResponse><params><param><value><string>SOME_STRING</string></value></param></params></methodResponse>'\r\nsend: \"POST /rpc/api HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: <SPACEWALK_HOST>\\r\\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\\r\\nUser-Agent: xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)\\r\\nContent-Type: text/xml\\r\\nContent-Length: 801\\r\\n\\r\\n<?xml version='1.0'?>\\n<methodCall>\\n<methodName>user.create</methodName>\\n<params>\\n<param>\\n<value><string>SOME_STRING</string></value>\\n</param>\\n<param>\\n<value><struct>\\n<member>\\n<name>use_pam_auth</name>\\n<value><string>1</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>firstName</name>\\n<value><string>['first</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>lastName</name>\\n<value><string>last1'</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>desiredLogin</name>\\n<value><string>['first.last1'</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>desiredPassword</name>\\n<value><string>SOMEPASSWORD</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>email</name>\\n<value><string>['first.last1'@someemail.com</string></value>\\n</member>\\n</struct></value>\\n</param>\\n</params>\\n</methodCall>\\n\"\r\nreply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n'\r\nheader: Date: SOME_DATE_TIME\r\r\nheader: Server: Apache\r\r\nheader: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\r\nheader: Content-Length: 462\r\r\nbody: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><int>-1</int></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value><string>redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcFault: Could not find method: create in class: com.redhat.rhn.frontend.xmlrpc.user.UserHandler with params: [com.redhat.rhn.domain.user.legacy.UserImpl, redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcStruct]</string></value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>'\r\n('Error creating user:', \"<Fault -1: 'redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcFault: Could not find method: create in class: com.redhat.rhn.frontend.xmlrpc.user.UserHandler with params: [com.redhat.rhn.domain.user.legacy.UserImpl, redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcStruct]'>\")\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["send: \"POST /rpc/api HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: <SPACEWALK_HOST>\\r\\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\\r\\nUser-Agent: xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)\\r\\nContent-Type: text/xml\\r\\nContent-Length: 237\\r\\n\\r\\n<?xml version='1.0'?>\\n<methodCall>\\n<methodName>auth.login</methodName>\\n<params>\\n<param>\\n<value><string>SPACEWALK_ADMIN</string></value>\\n</param>\\n<param>\\n<value><string>SOMEPASSWORD</string></value>\\n</param>\\n</params>\\n</methodCall>\\n\"", "reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n'", "header: Date: SOME_DATE_TIME", "", "header: Server: Apache", "", "header: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "", "header: Content-Length: 207", "", "body: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><methodResponse><params><param><value><string>SOME_STRING</string></value></param></params></methodResponse>'", "send: \"POST /rpc/api HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: <SPACEWALK_HOST>\\r\\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\\r\\nUser-Agent: xmlrpclib.py/1.0.1 (by www.pythonware.com)\\r\\nContent-Type: text/xml\\r\\nContent-Length: 801\\r\\n\\r\\n<?xml version='1.0'?>\\n<methodCall>\\n<methodName>user.create</methodName>\\n<params>\\n<param>\\n<value><string>SOME_STRING</string></value>\\n</param>\\n<param>\\n<value>**<struct>\\n<member>\\n<name>use_pam_auth</name>\\n<value><string>1</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>firstName</name>\\n<value><string>['first</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>lastName</name>\\n<value><string>last1'</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>desiredLogin</name>\\n<value><string>['first.last1'</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>desiredPassword</name>\\n<value><string>password</string></value>\\n</member>\\n<member>\\n<name>email</name>\\n<value><string>['first.last1'@someemail.com</string>**</value>\\n</member>\\n</struct></value>\\n</param>\\n</params>\\n</methodCall>\\n\"", "reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n'", "header: Date: SOME_DATE_TIME", "", "header: Server: Apache", "", "header: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "", "header: Content-Length: 462", "", "body: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><int>-1</int></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value><string>redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcFault: Could not find method: create in class: com.redhat.rhn.frontend.xmlrpc.user.UserHandler with params: [com.redhat.rhn.domain.user.legacy.UserImpl, redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcStruct]</string></value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>'", "('Error creating user:', \"<Fault -1: 'redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcFault: Could not find method: create in class: com.redhat.rhn.frontend.xmlrpc.user.UserHandler with params: [com.redhat.rhn.domain.user.legacy.UserImpl, redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcStruct]'>\")"]}
```

I am expecting these 3 scripts to list users from an IPA group, compare, and create local users in Spacewalk which do not match - since local users must exist in Spacewalk before a user can login using their IPA credentials - I am trying to automate the step of comparing and creating accounts.

I understand the python scripts could be merged, but this is where I have ended up trying to figure the issue out.

I first thought that the exception may be being caused by the parameters I was passing to it, but it doesn't seem to be the case, the method exists (according to official documentation), and I am passing the correct parameters (or so I believe).

```
Method: create
Description:
Create a new user.
Parameters:
string sessionKey
string desiredLogin - Desired login name, will fail if already in use.
string desiredPassword
string firstName
string lastName
string email - User's e-mail address.
int usePamAuth - 1 if you wish to use PAM authentication for this user, 0 otherwise.
Returns:

int - 1 on success, exception thrown otherwise.
```

I have tried to format the variable for the list of users differently, tried to omit the PAM parameter, and various ways of formatting the way the python script formulates the API command, but I haven't had any luck, and documentation for understanding is scarce on how to write Python scripts in this use case. Though examples do exist, they're not as intricate or complex as I'd like to learn from.

All my other scripts which query the Spacewalk API for software, patches, channels, users and system groups run fine, so this doesn't appear to be an issue with software versions.

NOTE: there doesn't appear to be a tag in Stack Overflow for "Spacewalk" or "Oracle Linux Manager", which surprises me...